# CSS - make all elements the same height as the tallest element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem where I have three floating buttons in a div. one of the buttons has more content that the others, so it's taller.

I want to be able to make all buttons the same height as the tallest button. I tried `height: 100%;` but that didn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style type="text/css">
    .container {
      width: 320px;
    }
    
    .container button {
      float: left;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
      width: 33.33%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button>
                <span class="big-text">Okay</span>
                <span class="little-text">123</span>
            </button>
    <button>
                <span class="big-text">Another Option</span>
                <span class="little-text">456</span>
            </button>
    <button>
                <span class="big-text">Nah!</span>
                <span class="little-text">789</span>
            </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpdxyaz6/1/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add `display:flex` to your container class like this:

```
.container {
    width: 320px;
    display:flex;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/xpdxyaz6/2/

---

**NOTE:**

As of May 2021, the `Flex` property compatibility for browsers are as follows:

**Google Chrome** Partial support with prefix **v4 - v20** | Full support with prefix **v21 - v28** | Full support **v29+**

**Mozilla Firefox** Partial support with prefix **v2 - v21** | Partial support **v22 - v27** | Full Support **v28+**

**Internet Explorer** Partial support with prefix **v10** | Partial support with prefix **v11+**

**Safari** Partial support with prefix **v3.1 - v6** | Full support with prefix **v6.1 - v8** | Full Support **v9+**

**Edge** Full support **v12+**

Comment: Worth mentioning flex doesn't have perfect browser support. http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: @TalyaS Browser support info added. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: `display: flex` is virulently applied to all children and cannot be undone. This is often undesirable, so this solution can typically only be used if there are only few children.

Answer (score 4):

How about using `min-height`? updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fq96qy2/)

```css
 .container {
   width: 320px;
 }
 .container button {
   float: left;
   background: #FFFFFF;
   border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
   width: 33.33%;
   min-height: 40px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>
    <span class="big-text">Okay</span>
    <span class="little-text">123</span>
  </button>
  <button>
    <span class="big-text">Another Option</span>
    <span class="little-text">456</span>
  </button>
  <button>
    <span class="big-text">Nah!</span>
    <span class="little-text">789</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this cross browser without `display:flex` with the CSS rules `padding-bottom: 999999em;`and
`margin-bottom: -999999em;`on the floated element this will force the webbrowser to render an equal height. And you need an `overflow: hidden` on the parent element

see demo https://jsfiddle.net/xpdxyaz6/3/